# How to set color to the selected item in listview and at the same time the other items should not be selected (in android)?

Tags: android, listview

How to set color to the selected item in listview and at the same time the other items should not be selected (in android)?

Thanks in advance,
Neha

Answer (score 0):

Go with registering the `onItemClickListener()` on your listview and get the view and set colot like this

```
listview
                    .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

Comment: @Rohit: I have tried this way, but its not working exactly. Using this when i select a row from listview, it changes the colour of some other row from list.And i dont know why this is happening. Can u please help me out? Thanks, Neha

Comment: Now I am pretty sure that the problem is in your `getView()` method of your adapter. It seems that you have not managed the `View` instance of the `getView()` of your adapter. You should check that weather your View instance in your getView() is either null or not. Please refer to this link http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Comment: @Rohit: i am sending my piece of code. Can you please tell me where I a going wrong?

Comment: list2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView a, View v, int position, long id) { String s2 = ((TextView)((LinearLayout) ((RelativeLayout)a.getChildAt(position)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getText().toString();
                String ID2 = ((TextView)((LinearLayout) ((RelativeLayout)a.getChildAt(position)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).getText().toString();

Comment: String Type = ((TextView)((LinearLayout) ((RelativeLayout)a.getChildAt(position)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(2)).getText().toString();
    String MenuItemID = ((TextView)((LinearLayout) ((RelativeLayout)a.getChildAt(position)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(3)).getText().toString();

    dbHelper db = new dbHelper(ActiveMenu.this);
    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();

Comment: Cursor c = db.getSubMenuData(Long.parseLong(ID2));
    if (c.getCount() > 0)
    {
     c.moveToFirst();
     while (c.isAfterLast()==false) {

      if( c.getString(3).substring(0).equals("S"))
      {

       map.put("Item Name", c.getString(0).substring(0));
       map.put("Item ID",c.getString(4).substring(0));
       map.put("Item Type", c.getString(3).substring(0));
       map.put("MenuItemID", c.getString(5).substring(0));
       
       mylist.add(map);
       map = new HashMap<String, String>();

      }
      c.moveToNext();
     }

Comment: mSchedule2 = new SimpleAdapter(ActiveMenu.this, mylist, R.layout.listview,
       new String[] { "Item Name", "Item ID", "Item Type","MenuItemID" },
       new int[] { R.id.TextViewMain, R.id.TextViewID,
       R.id.TextViewType,R.id.TextViewMenuItemID});
     list2.setAdapter(mSchedule2);
    }
    else
    {
     c.close();
     Intent intent = new Intent(ActiveMenu.this,MenuItemList.class); 
     intent.putExtra("submenuID", ID2);
     intent.putExtra("submenuname", s2);
     startActivity(intent);
     }

   }

  });

Comment: @Rohit: Can u please tell that in this piece of code, where should i change the colour of row from list on click event?

Comment: in your itemclicklister's onCLick method, I have observed that you have used the instance if AdapterView to do the things. Leave that and use v i.e. object of View (parameter in onCLick)  and on that object do this v.setBackgroundColor(color);